# Appium Inspector Loading image issue and no operation on second native page by appium

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I have two query. could any one provide valuable time to resolve below query?

1. Suppose I logged any login application on first page .then how can we perform another operation with latest appium desktop server on second page because I tried a lot to find xpath of any single element on second page (after login ,it seems that new page loaded )for performing any basic operation(click) but I got the error as no such element exception and unable to proceed with second page. After this I went to Google and tried to analyze but I didn’t get finalize solution for the same could you please help me on this?
2. As per my hobbies as surfing or exploring more features , i just came to know that we have another appium inspector for identify the element but some time , I am not getting image properly loaded in Appium emulator after starting session with desire capabilities in appium desktop window and getting page as loading after couple of minute but I can see app source for the same app and also not able to identify object or perform any operation for those application where page did not load up. Could you please provide valuable time to resolve loading issue in Appium inspector for any APK if you get a chance to have this issue?.

i have checked second page that is also native page and also have two native page after login but i can not see any alert or pop up and see another new native page then i tried to switch with driver context handler but still did n't identify any element on second page and also got error as no such element exception on second exception after login successfully by code.

Comment: For your query 1: Can you please add screen shot of the screen with UI Automator View?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.